# Grails link id not getting sent back to the server

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a GSP that gets rendered as follows:

```
class MyController {
    def start() {
        Widget widgetr = getSomehow()
        render(
            view: "test",
            model: widget
        )
    }

    def doSomething() {
        long fizzId = params.fizzId as Long
        // do something with 'fizzId'...
    }
}
```

In the GSP I have a `g:link`:

```
<g:link action="doSomething" id="${widget.fizzId}">Click me to do something!</g:link>
```

When the user clicks that link, I want the `MyController#doSomething` action executed, and I want the `widget.fizzId` (`Long`) sent to that action as a param (e.g. `params.fizzId`).

When I run this I get a `NullPointerException` converting `params.fizzId` to a Long because its null.

What can I do to make this work? According to the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) I would think this is what the `id` attribute is for, but it seems like I'm using it incorrectly. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make the model you return from your controller a `Map` instance, e.g.

```
def start() {
    Widget widgetr = getSomehow()
    render(
        view: "test",
        model: [widget: widgetr]
    )
}
```

In your `link` tag, you need to set the `params` attribute rather than the `id` attribute, because the parameter you're sending is not named `id`

```
<g:link action="doSomething" params="${[fizzId: widget.fizzId]}">
    Click me to do something!
</g:link>
```